How to upload caption to Youtube using rest API
I am struggling while trying to upload programmatically Youtube captions, following the official documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/insert.
I tried many things with postman:
1/ pass the snippet in the body: caption file is missing
2/ use form-data and try to add both the file and the snippet data: data are not found.
(I tried multiple ways to try to pass the snippet info together with the caption file. ex: snippet.language, snippet["language"], snippet and pass a stringified json...)
Using FormData
Using Raw Json
Example of request Using Raw Json
curl --location 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer xxx.yyy.zzz' \
--data '{
  "snippet": {
    "language": "fr",
    "name": "Spanish captions",
    "videoId": "flz-udcavwE",
    "isDraft": false
  }
}

Example of request using FormData
curl --location 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions/?part=snippet' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer xxx.yyy.zzz' \
--form 'caption=@"tnGz3GV3E/captions.sbv"' \
--form 'snippet="{\"snippet\":{\"language\":\"fr\",\"name\":\"fr\"&\"videoId\":\"flz-udcavwE\"}}"

Please help to construct properly that call!

welcome to stack please edit your question and include [example] not images of code

thank you @LindaLawton-DaImTo. I added the CURL requests. I hope it helps to reproduce :)
